# Do we have $(f^{-1}(\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}A}))(\operatorname{Spec}B)=A$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Given a morphism of schemes $f:\operatorname{Spec}B\to\operatorname{Spec}A$, do we have $(f^{-1}(\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}A}))(\operatorname{Spec}B)=A$?

Answer (score 7):

No, suppose $A = k[x]$ and $B = k[x] / (x)$ for some field $k$, and $f$ corresponds to the quotient map $A \to B$.  Then $\Gamma(\operatorname{Spec} B, f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A})) \simeq k[x]_{(x)}$.

Comment: I can see that your last statement is true for the presheaf $$U \mapsto \varinjlim \mathcal O_Y(V)$$ where the limit runs over all open sets $V$ of $Y$ containing $f(U)$.  But how do you know it is true for the associated sheaf $f^{-1}\mathcal O_Y$?

Comment: @D_S Ah, good point.  I think I'll remove that part of the answer.

Answer (score 6):

If $i$ is the inclusion of an open subset $U$ of a scheme $X$, then $i^{-1}\mathcal O_X = \mathcal O_{X|U}$.  In particular, $i^{-1}\mathcal O_X(U) = \mathcal O_{X|U}(U) = \mathcal O_X(U)$.  With this in mind, you get a counterexample by letting $f$ be the inclusion of a principal open subset into an affine scheme.

Answer (score -7):

I believe the following holds: If $f: X \rightarrow S$ is a map of schemes and if $p \neq q\in X$ are points with $f(p)=f(q):=s \in S$ you get a canonical isomorphism

$$f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_S)_p \cong \mathcal{O}_{S,s}\cong f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_S)_q.$$

Since $p \neq q$ we do not have an isomorphism

$$ \mathcal{O}_{X,p}\neq \mathcal{O}_{X,q}$$

in general. Hence $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_S) \neq \mathcal{O}_X$ in general.

**Question:** "Do we have $f^{-1}(Spec(A))(Spec(B))=B$?"

**Answer:** We have a canonical map

$$f(Spec(B)): f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_{Spec(A)})(Spec(B)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Spec(B)}(Spec(B))\cong B,$$

but since the sheaves $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_{Spec(A)})$ and $\mathcal{O}_{Spec(B)}$ differ the map $f(Spec(B))$ is not an isomorphism in general.

**Note:** If there is a spelling mistake in the question, and we replace $A$ with $B$
the answer is positive when the map is an open immersion:

There seems to be some confusion on an exercise on adjoint functors.
If you look in Hartshorne Chapter II.1 you will find for any map of topological space $f: X\rightarrow Y$ (exercise 1.18) an isomorphism

$$M1.\text{   }Hom_X(f^{-1}G, F)\cong Hom_Y(G, f_*F).$$

Hence if $F:=(\tilde{f}, f^{\#}): X \rightarrow S$ is a map of schemes there is canonically a map of sheaves of rings on $X$:

$$f: \tilde{f}^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_S)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X.$$

The map $f$ corresponds to the map

$$f^{\#}: \mathcal{O}_S \rightarrow \tilde{f}_*\mathcal{O}_X$$

via the isomorphism $M1$. If $X:=Spec(B), S:=Spec(A)$ it follows the map $f$ is a map of sheaves of rings on $X$, not on $S$. Hence it does not make any sense to evaulate $f$ at $S$, since $S$ is not an open set in $X$. It only makes sense to evaluate $f$ at $X:=Spec(B)$. Moreover $A$ is not a subring of $B$ hence you never recover $A$ from $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ or $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$.

**Example 1.** Let $S:=Spec(A), X:=D(f)$ for $f\in A$. We get an inclusion of the basic open set $D(f)$ into $S$:

$$\tilde{i}: X:=D(f) \rightarrow S$$

and a canonical map

$$i: \tilde{i}^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_S) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{D(f)},$$

and the map $i$ is an isomorphism: You may check that $\tilde{i}^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_S)\cong \mathcal{O}_{D(f)}$. In this special case you get an isomorphism

$$ i(D(f)): \tilde{i}^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_S)(D(f)) \cong A_f \cong\mathcal{O}_{D(f)}(D(f)),$$

but you do not get an isomorphism in general.

The natural question to ask is: for a general map of rings $\phi: A \rightarrow B,$

**Question:** Is the canonical map

$$f(X):\tilde{f}^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_S)(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(X) \cong B$$

an isomorphism?"

**Answer:** The answer is "no", by the argument given in the previous post.

**Note:** if you take the "pull back"

$$F^*(\mathcal{O}_S)$$

you get

$$F^*(\mathcal{O}_S):= \mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{\tilde{f}^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_S)} \tilde{f}^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_S) \cong \mathcal{O}_X$$

hence

$$F^*(\mathcal{O}_X)(X)\cong \mathcal{O}_X(X) \cong B.$$

To people reacting negatively to this, denouncing it as "vandalism": Do exercise II.1.18 in HH and consult the definition of the notion "morphism of schemes" in Chapter II in HH.

Comment: The question is about equality of global sections, not equality of sheaves or their stalks. This doesn't answer the question, and it doesn't add anything to the answers from 2017, which give two very nice explicit counterexamples.

Comment: You have tried to edit the question in a way that completely changes what is asked. I rejected this vandalistic edit. You should change your answer to match the question, not change the question to match your answer! Also, the (algebraic-topology) tag is clearly not appropriate here.

Comment: I still don't understand why you think the question is "wrong". Let $X = \mathrm{Spec}(B)$ and $Y = \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ be affine schemes. A map of rings $A\to B$ gives rise to a map of schemes $f\colon X\to Y$. Part of the data of a map of schemes is a map of sheaves $O_Y\to f_*O_X$, which on global sections $A =  O_Y(Y)\to f_*O_X(Y) = B$ is the original map of rings $A\to B$. Via the pushforward/pullback adjunction, we also get a map of sheaves $f^{-1}O_Y\to O_X$. (continued)

Comment: I think it is very reasonable to wonder whether this map is also the original map $A\to B$ on global sections $f^{-1}O_Y(X)\to O_X(X) = B$. So it is very reasonable to wonder whether $f^{-1}O_Y(X) = A$, as the original question asked - *more* reasonable, I think, than to expect the induced map $f^{-1}O_Y(X)\to O_X(X)$ be an isomorphism, which is what you address in your answer. In any case, I'll say it again: it is entirely inappropriate to change the meaning of someone else's question to match what *you* think they should be asking.